# Notifications API with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, notifications

I am trying to send notification to one of my users (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/) but I can't manage to get this work with my PHP SDK.

I am using this code:

```
$data = array(
    'href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
    'access_token'=> $app_token,
    'template'=> 'test'
);
$sendnotification = $facebook->api('/USER_ID/notifications', 'post', $data);
```

And this is what error I get back:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token
>   signature. thrown in /usr/home/test/base_facebook.php on line 1039

This is how I get app access token:

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "MY_APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "MY_APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

There was a problem with access_token, if I use access token directly in sode it now works.

```
'access_token'=> 'K3Rds2y0cGm...',
```

Does anyone knows how long app access token lasts?

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct way to set an Application Access Token when you use the Facebook PHP SDK V3.2.0 :

```
    $this->_objFacebook->setAccessToken($this->_objFacebook->getAppId().'|'.$this->_objFacebook->getAppSecret());
```

Answer (score 4):

the poblem is that the var $app_token is a string in the form of $app_token = "access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"

what you need to use is the second part, YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, therefore, before using $app_token as a valid token, you must delete the first part of the string  "access_token="

solution:

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "MY_APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "MY_APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
$app_token = str_replace("access_token=", "", $app_token);

$data = array(
    'href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
    'access_token'=> $app_token,
    'template'=> 'test'
);
$sendnotification = $facebook->api('/USER_ID/notifications', 'post', $data);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

```
$accessToken = $appId . '|' . $secret;
$params = array(
            'access_token' => $accessToken,
            'href' => $canvasPage,
            'template' => $message,
        );
$facebookObject->api('/' . $userId . '/notifications/', 'post', $params);
```

This works for me.
Reference: http://calibrate.be/labs/facebook-notification-api-php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if OAuth is enabled in the php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the access token you're using works in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - there's nowhere in your code that's actually verifying the request to retrieve the app access token worked.

Also you need to check that the app is both

1. Not in sandbox mode (may not be relevant, but worth checking)
2. Not configured as 'Native/Desktop' in the advanced settings - the app access token isn't trusted in that configuration

Comment: It is not in sandbox mode and configured as web.

Comment: Wait, were you just passing the result of file_get_contents into a variable and using it directly? Doesn't that also return an additional string before the token itself?